# How to enumerate registered COM servers

Tags: c#, com, enumeration

**Is there any "high level" method to enumerate the registered COM servers in C#?**

I would like to avoid direct registry access and also prefer to get some sort of list of "objects" containing at least following info:

- server name (human readable identification)
- CLSID aka GUID
- version
- server path and filename

Comment: Just do not hesitate to leave a comment even if you don't like the question. Thanks!

Comment: Why?  Just knowing the CLSID (and being able to create the object) isn't going to get you anything.

Comment: Let's have 3rd party COM components which you might want to dynamically reference in your app. You don't know all of them. You offer a list to the user, he selects a component and lets you know what kind of component (he thinks) he selects. Its up to you to detect the component provides the interface you know and which matches the type the user entered. The same approach is used in Visual Studio, when you add "static" reference to the COM to the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your followup comments, you're probably looking for [Component Categories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692689%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which allow COM objects to declare the "kind" of object that they are.  COM has the [ICatInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd542655%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface, which allows you to [enumerate categories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693458%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and [also to enumerate classes that implement a particular category](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687278%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).